# Update plot over images with scrollbar in a GUI using listeners

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I trying to create a GUI in which I plot several points over some images.
I have a scrollbar that update the image being shown and I need that those points keep being ploted over any image that I select using the scrollbar.
I created a class where I store the GUI handles, the points coordinates and the listener. Also, I created several methods, including one to create the listener and another one to plot the points whenever the user update the image.
Here is a piece of my code:

```
    classdef CircularRoi < handle
    properties
        x       = [];
        y       = [];
        xc      = [];
        yc      = [];
        handles = [];
        hl      = [];
    end
    properties (SetObservable = true)
        slice = [];
    end

    methods
        function obj = CircularRoi(hdl, value)
            obj.handles = hdl;
            obj.slice   = value;
            obj.addListener;
        end
        function addListener(obj)
            obj.hl = addlistener(obj.handles.sld_img, ...
                'Value', 'PostSet', ...
                @(src, event)plotRoi(obj, src, event));
        end
        function getRoi(obj, hdl, src, event)
            obj.getRoiCircle;
            obj.slice = get(hdl.sld_img, 'Value');
        end
        function plotRoi(obj, src, event)
            axeshandle = obj.handles.axs_img;
            obj.slice = get(obj.handles.sld_img, 'Value');
            disp(obj.slice)
            txt = findobj(get(axeshandle, 'Children'), 'Type', 'Text');
%             img = findobj(get(axeshandle, 'Children'), 'Type', 'Image');
%             img = img(1);
            delete(txt);
%             imshow(get(img, 'CData'), [], 'parent', axeshandle);
            plot(axeshandle, obj.x, obj.y, '*b', obj.xc', obj.yc', 'c');
            for ii = 1: length(obj.x)
                text(obj.x(ii), obj.y(ii), num2str(ii), 'color', 'c', 'Parent', axeshandle);
            end
        end
```

My problem is, when I update the image using the scrollbar, the plotRoi function is called and the points are ploted, but as soon as that happens, they disappear, as if the image is ploted over them.

Any idea of what is going on?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's not because you didn't call `hold on`? Also nowhere in your code do you create an image. Is it the commented-out call to `imshow`?

Comment: Yes, yes... Solved! Thank you!